# Scala pass trait to abtract class

Tags: class, scala, abstract-class

I would like to pass a trait to an abstract class using scala, this is what I have so far :

```
trait User extends VertexFrame {}

trait Member extends VertexFrame {}

object Member extends Base[Member] {}

object User extends Base[User] {}

abstract class Base[T <: VertexFrame: Manifest] {
  // Here if want to be able to access my "trait User" or my "trait Member"
  def list = {
   graph.frameVertices(graph.getVertices, manifest[T].runtimeClass).toList
  }
}
```

graph : http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/frames/2.0.0/com/tinkerpop/frames/FramedGraph.html

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing.  What is it exactly that you want to do in `Base` that is based on the type of `T` supplied?  What do you want to do that you have not yet been able to do and are thus asking SO for help on?

Comment: @cmbaxter In my abstract class I would like my test method to return classOf the trait passed to Base (Member or User)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this is what you are looking for (based on your comment):

```
abstract class Base[T <: VertexFrame: Manifest] { self =>
  // Here if want to be able to access my "trait User" or my "trait Member"
  def test = manifest[T].runtimeClass
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer I don't get any errors anymore. However when I pass the class I take from the manifest to a Java library : tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/frames/2.0.0/com/tinkerpop/frames/…, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class) it returns me an iterable of type Any instead of an iterable of type MyTrait. Do you know why ?

Comment: Can you post an updated code sample showing you calling into this Java library?

Comment: It's ugly, but you can include a cast like this `manifest[T].runtimeClass.asInstanceOf[Class[T]]` and that might fix your issue.  Before, a `Class[_]` was being returned.  The cast makes it a `Class[T]` which should work when passed into the java code you are calling.  There is probably a much better way to do with with scala 2.10 reflection, but this should work too.

Answer (score 0):

In your code generic type is redundant. Your companion objects extends abstract Base class, this can be used in self type annotation like @om-nom-nom showed